# Why didn't they wait to get a better "time phase correction" device instead of sending Data back?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the Star Trek: The Next Generation episode "Time's Arrow", they found

> Data's severed head from the future.

As a result, they were being very cautious with him and didn’t want to send him with a landing party to beam down. However, Data had a phase discriminator built into him that could allow him (with the help of other equipment) achieve the variance necessary to see the invisible beings.

Maybe this wasn't dangerous per se but it certainly seemed like a risk (especially without two-way communication). Why didn't they wait until they were better-equipped and could send someone instead of Data, since they were on high alert to protect him? There didn't seem to be a rush for time.

Comment: I think this is two questions.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite maybe but I was thinking the explanation as to how it worked may affect the part as to why the captain allowed Data to take the risk

Comment: could be! You are of course welcome to edit it back in.

Answer (score 8):

**Data *was* their better equipment.**

Here's a transcript from the show:

> DATA: Geordi, it indicates a synchronic distortion in the areas emanating triolic waves.
>
> LAFORGE: That explains a few things. How much, Data?
>
> DATA [OC]: A positive displacement of point zero zero four percent.
>
> LAFORGE: Well, whatever or whoever is there, we're out of phase with it, but we're only talking by a fraction of a second.
>
> WORF: A fraction of a second would make them invisible?
>
> LAFORGE: A millisecond, a year, it wouldn't make any difference. If what we're reading is true, then we're occupying the same space but in a different time.
>
> RIKER: How do we compensate?
>
> DATA: Commander, we might be able to manipulate the synchronic distortion.
>
> LAFORGE: Maybe. If we were to create a contained subspace force field.  But to get a point zero zero four variance, we'd need an incredibly sensitive phase discriminator, Data. I don't think we've got one that would come close.
>
> DATA: Yes, we do. It is built into my positronic decompiler. It will be necessary for me to join the away team, sir.
>
> PICARD: (hesitation) Proceed, Mister Data.

Geordi doesn't say that they don't have a phase discriminator *onboard* that would come close to their needs, he simply says *he doesn't think they have one.*  The implication is that he doesn't know of any tool available which could provide this functionality.  This isn't a case of "Reg, replicate me a spanner."  The tool Geordi needs to do this isn't available...

...until Data reminds him that his decompiler contains just such a part.

Sure, the *Enterprise* could have stayed in orbit for a week or so while they scanned Data's head, replicated a new phase discriminator, built it into a tool, and then beamed back down, but there's a big reason why Picard decides to send Data instead:

Dianna is convinced there are hundreds of invisible frightened humans in a cave which contains the same radiation as an ancient structure on Earth.  Picard says as much in a later briefing in that episode:

> PICARD: We must assume that there is a threat, if not to us then to 19th century Earth. We have to determine what that threat may be.

They don't have the time to spend building a brand new tool and training somebody on how to tune it, when they have Data.  But then they lose Data and have to build such a device anyway:

> LAFORGE: It's not going to be easy to reproduce what Data did. We can create a contained subspace field, but we'd need an extraordinarily sensitive phase discriminator to get that point zero zero four variance.
>
> PICARD: Can you build one?
>
> LAFORGE: It won't be as good as Data's.
>
> RIKER: Will it be good enough?
>
> LAFORGE: I don't know. I can try. It's going to take some time though.
>
> PICARD: I don't want anyone else going in alone.
>
> LAFORGE: I can probably create a large enough subspace field to encompass everyone. But adjusting the phase inside the field, that's going to be the hard part.

For the sake of his friend, Geordi will "try" to build one, but at this point he's not 100% convinced he will succeed.  Picard couldn't leave perhaps hundreds of humans, AND a time-travel threat against his own past, on the hook for Geordi to "try" when Data was available, now.  Only once Data disappeared could the crew morally fall back on "maybe" building one "good enough" to "possibly" do the job.

So how long did the events take?  We don't really have an answer.  We do have the stardates though:

- 45959.1 : The *Enterprise* is recalled to Earth and find's Data's head
- 45960.2 : Back onboard ship, they go to Davidia 3, and Data disappears
- 45965.3 : The new phase discriminator is brought online.

This isn't entirely helpful, because Stardates were specifically invented to imply the passage of time without actually stating the amount of time which passes (insert mumbo jumbo about warp space causing time differentials, etc).  What we DO know is that the "4" stands for the 24th century, the 5 stands for "season 5," and the show takes place at the end of the season (because it's near the top of the season's 1000 stardates.)  The dot is supposed to be a day designator (although sometime between Season 1 and Season 6 it changed to an hour designator). (https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stardate)

If we go by the book, *hours* will seem like *days*... (sorry).  If we go with the "hours" mechanic, we would need to suppose that surveying the tunnel system on Earth, collecting Data's head, investigating it, travel to Davidia 3, the initial planetary survey, the first away team's landing, Data beaming down, betting lost, and then the new device being online took about 5 days.  If we go by the "days" mechanic, however, we get the idea that travel took a week, surveying took another week, and Data has been missing for days or maybe even a week or two before LaForge has a new discriminator available.

In the same time ([because the clock in San Dimas is always running](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SanDimasTime)), Data has sharked a poker game, gotten a fancy hotel room, found fancy clothing, made friends with the bellhop, and built an extensive piece of technology out of "bearskins and stone clubs."  San Francisco wasn't exactly the super-diverse city it is today in the time he's in;  it's likely some parts had to be shipped, at a time when shipping meant actual sailing ships.

Data's side of the story really argues for the "longer form" stardates;  and if the longer form stardates hold true in Season 5, it makes sense why Picard would have sent Data down.  **Picard was only willing to "cheat fate" to a point for Data; With Earth's history and possible human prisoners on the line, and a jerryrigged discriminator days, maybe weeks in the future, they would need to use a resource NOW to see these aliens.**

Comment: "They don't have the time to spend building a brand new tool and training somebody on how to tune it," so I guess Picard was wrong on this assumption as they spent a day building a new one and still saved Earth?

Comment: You work with the tools and data you have, @Celeritas. When Picard sent Data down, the data he had made it seem like a crushing emergency, and the only tool he had was Data. The only rational decision was to send Data down. Once Data was lost (because they didn't know WHEN Data was going to be lost, it was totally possible that this was NOT the mission he'd disappear) they still had a problem, but now they HAD to build a tool.